# ExoPlayer PlayerView OnClickListener not working

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

In my app, I want to handle user click on `PlayerView`  however `OnClickListener`  not being called and no exception is thrown. I added `app:use_controller="false"` 
to XML  `PlayerView`.

I tried to set `OnTouchListener` but I need `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` to be called which is also not happening(because I don't want to handle the case when the user is scrolling, I need to handle the case when the user taps on PlayerView).

```
  class FeedHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView displayName, jobTitle, action, date, likedBy;
        private ImageIndicator profile_pic;
        private ImageView videoOptions, likeImage, shareImage;
        private PlayerView playerView;
        private WebView webView;

        @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        FeedHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            profile_pic = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
            likedBy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_like_by);
            date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
            likeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_like);
            shareImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_share);
            displayName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_display_name);
            jobTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_job_title);
            action = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_action);
            videoOptions = itemView.findViewById(R.id.video_options);
            playerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exo_player);
            webView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new AnimationWebViewClient());
            webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        }
    }


@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull FeedHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.playerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ...
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: post your code.

Comment: @AIK I have just edited

Comment: What version of exp player are you using?

Comment: Try adding `playerView.requestFocus()`

Answer (score 25):

You can use:

```
video.setControllerAutoShow(false);
video.setUseController(false);
video.getVideoSurfaceView().setOnClickListener(view -> {
          Log.e("GET", "clicked!");
          if(player.getPlayWhenReady()){
               player.setPlayWhenReady(false);
          }else{
               player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
          }
});
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer!!! Thank you buddy

Comment: its not woking in exoplayer . it is another solution i want to single or double  click on playerview and set functionality about it but none found anything about it

Comment: it's work fine bro, you can use double click and single click, look at new answer from me.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to do this to handle any scenario of interaction with the player, suppose you want to add features to skip or come back 10 seconds like youtube.

**This is my fragment**

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    private void setOnGestureListeners() {
        mPlayerView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(requireActivity()){
            @Override
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                super.onSwipeRight();
                // Swipe to the right
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                super.onSwipeLeft();
                // Swipe to the left
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                super.onClick();
                // User tapped once (This is what you want)
            }

            @Override
            public void onDoubleClick() {
                super.onDoubleClick();
                // User tapped twice
            }
        });
    }
```

**OnSwipeTouchListener.java**

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private static final String TAG = "OnSwipeTouchListener";

    private final GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context context) {
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(context, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onSwipeRight: Swiped to the RIGHT");
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onSwipeLeft: Swiped to the LEFT");
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onSwipeTop: Swiped to the TOP");
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onSwipeBottom: Swiped to the BOTTOM");
    }

    public void onClick() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onClick: Clicking in the screen");
    }

    public void onDoubleClick() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onClick: Clicking TWO TIMES in the screen");
    }

    public void onLongClick() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onLongClick: LONG click in the screen");
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            onClick();
            return super.onSingleTapUp(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            onDoubleClick();
            return super.onDoubleTap(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            onLongClick();
            super.onLongPress(e);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                        result = true;
                    }
                } else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

These are some Exoplayer projects, in case you want.

[UsagesOfExoplayer](https://github.com/soonsam123/UsagesOfExoplayer)

[ExoPlayerSample by Yusuf](https://github.com/yusufcakmak/ExoPlayerSample)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this solution will work.

```
playerView.hideController();
playerView.setControllerVisibilityListener(new PlayerControlView.VisibilityListener() {
    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
            playerView.hideController();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: set on click listener required to custom work not show controller.

Answer (score 0):

create dobule click listener class:

```
class DoubleClickListener constructor(onDoubleClickListener: OnDoubleClickListener): View.OnClickListener {

private var interval: Long = 200L

private var handler: Handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()!!)

private var onDoubleClickListener: OnDoubleClickListener? = null

private var click = 0

private var isBusy: Boolean = false

init {
    this.onDoubleClickListener = onDoubleClickListener
}


public interface OnDoubleClickListener{
    fun onClick()

    fun onDoubleClick()
}

override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
    if(!isBusy){
        isBusy = true

        click++

        handler.postDelayed({
            if(click >= 2){
                onDoubleClickListener?.onDoubleClick()
            }

            if(click == 1){
                onDoubleClickListener?.onClick()
            }

            click = 0
        }, interval)

        isBusy = false
    }
}
```

}

add on your play activity:

```
val playerView: PlayerView = findViewById(R.id.videoView)
playerView.useController = false
playerView.videoSurfaceView?.setOnClickListener(DoubleClickListener(object :
        DoubleClickListener.OnDoubleClickListener{
        override fun onClick() {

            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Single clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            if(player.isPlaying){
                player.pause()
            }else{
                player.play()
            }
        }

        override fun onDoubleClick() {
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Double clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            like.setButtonChecked(true)
        }
    }))
```

work fine for me